# Skipping the unmatched Index lines pyspark

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to skip the lines which are out of list index, i.e keep only the lines which are matching to given index.

Following is my data,

```
12,34,5,6,7,8,.......

23,45,657,78,34,.......

0,2,34

15,78,65,78,9,...
```

**I want to extract the fields x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]** also in my dataset some lines have less fields and it will throw list index out of range, SO I want to skipp the lines having index <3. How could I achieve this in spark python

This i tried,

```
def takeOnly3fields(data):
    for row in data:
        if not len(row) <=3:
            return ",".join(row) 

ff = file1.map(takeOnly3fields)
print(ff.collect()) will return NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: Your code or at least the function you have written, will help us better :-)

Comment: map will iterate for you, if you are using a single dimensional list and no need of for loop inside.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is single dimensional, following is the code you need:

```
def takeOnly3fields(data):
    return ",".join(data) if len(data)>3 else None
```

map will iterate the entire data for you and you just need a transformation function on the data set.